# Enterprise library 4.1 logging for sharepoint web.config throwing error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, enterprise-library

I am trying to using Enterprise library 4.1 in Sharepoint 2007 (MOSS). Till I used only Enterprise Data application in sharepoint it is working fine. Just I started using logging also site throwing Not related exceptions.

**web.config**

in configuration section

```
<section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.
 Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
    requirePermission="true" />
```

Safe Controls section

```
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.Unity" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.Unity" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
<SafeControl Assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

Logging configuration section

```
 <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        source="Enterprise Library Logging" formatter="Text Formatter"
        log="SPE SharePoint Event Log" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack" />
      <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        fileName="rolling.log" formatter="Text Formatter" rollInterval="Day"
        traceOutputOptions="LogicalOperationStack, DateTime, Timestamp, ProcessId, ThreadId, Callstack" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}"
        name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </allEvents>
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
```

In Assemblies Section

```
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
<add assembly="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

Page was showing different error.

```
This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPageUserException: This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.

Source Error: 


Line 254:
Line 255:
Line 256:    <WebPartPages:ContentEditorWebPart ID="ContentEditorWebPart2" runat="server" __MarkupType="xmlmarkup" WebPart="true" __WebPartId="BBAABEB8-E66E-48ec-AB3B-CB0AD46757B3" >
Line 257:<WebPart xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
Line 258:  <Title>Click the link below to manage your groups:</Title>


Source File: c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\MYSPE\TabsUserCotrol.ascx    Line: 256 

Stack Trace: 


[WebPartPageUserException: This page has encountered a critical error. Contact your system administrator if this problem persists.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControls.RethrowExceptionIfNeeded() +43
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SafeControls.IsSafeControl(Type type, String& unsafeErrorMessage) +52
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.TypeCache.get_Item(Type type) +144
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.EmbeddedXmlReader..ctor(TextReader reader, Type type, SPWeb spWeb) +106
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart.AddParsedSubObject(Object obj) +990
   System.Web.UI.Control.System.Web.UI.IParserAccessor.AddParsedSubObject(Object obj) +10
   ASP._controltemplates_myspe_tabsusercotrol_ascx.__BuildControlContentEditorWebPart2() in c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\MYSPE\TabsUserCotrol.ascx:256
   ASP._controltemplates_myspe_tabsusercotrol_ascx.__BuildControl__control13(Control __ctrl) in c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\MYSPE\TabsUserCotrol.ascx:238
   System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container) +12
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartZone.GetInitialWebParts() +106
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartManager.RegisterZone(WebZone zone) +186
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebZone.OnInit(EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartZone.OnInit(EventArgs e) +9
```

**If I remove above code from web.config then site is working fine. I not understanding where I am missing.**

please hel me out to find me solution.

Comment: it is not recommended to modify webapp's web.config file, sharepoint automatically logs everything in event viewer/ULS logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the SafeControl Section entries and Assemblies Section entries for the Enterprise Library.  I don't think you need those at all.  I've used EntLib2.0/SharePoint 2007 and EntLib5.0/SharePoint 2010 and never had those sections in my web.config.